# How to open the jfr partial file

Tags: java, jfr

When I use the configuration like below in my application, it always gets some xxx.jfr.part file.
How can I open the XXX.jfr.part file in Java Flight Recorder tool?
How can I change the configuration to create a less .part file?

The configuration in my app:
-XX:+FlightRecorder 
-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,disk=true,maxsize=200m,maxage=3h,repository=/${MyApplicationPath}/log/jfr

The partial file which can not be opened:
|MyApplicationPath
__|log
____|jfr
_______|2018_11_14_05_33_06_17296
___________|2018_11_14_05_33_07_17296_0.jfr.part 2,727KB
___________|2018_11_14_05_33_07_17296_0.jfr  0KB

Answer (score 5):

The .part file represents an unfinished file. The recommended way to extract data from the disk repository is to use the jcmd tool.

Oracle JDK 7/8 (which you seem to be using)

```
jcmd <pid> JFR.dump recording=0 filename=dump.jfr
```

It will finish the .part file and copy out the data in a safe manner. It's not possible to a read .part file, since important information on how to parse the file is located at the end.

Comment: Do we have any way to add the configuration to JVM args to automatically generate the jfr file or command to flush the buffer to the jfr file?

Comment: -XX:StartFlightrecording=dumponexit=true,filename=dump.jfr will write the recording when the JVM exits. It is also possible to specify a duration, for example  -XX:StartFlightrecording=duration=30s,filename=dump.jfr, to dump the recording after 30 s